# Смена картинки при клике

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как написать на *Jquery* функцию, которая будет при нажатии на иконку плюс (изображение plus.gif) будет менять его на минус (изображение minus.gif) и наоборот? То есть при нажатии на минус обратно возвращается изображению плюса.

```
<div id="main">
    <li><img id="icon" src="img/plus.gif" onclick="imgsrc(this)" >Россия
        <ul>
            <div id="RusOne"><li>Пейзажи</li></div>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему бы не сделать на css с заменой фона просто, зачем так извращаться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function imgsrc(img) {
  if ($(img).attr("src") == "img/plus.gif")
    $(img).attr("src", "img/minus.gif");
  else
    $(img).attr("src", "img/plus.gif");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ответ из области "никогда так не делайте, хоть это и работает" :D

```js
$("#icon").click(function(){ 
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').split('').reverse().join(""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="/img/plus.gif?fig.sunim/gmi/" id="icon">
```

*отсутствие толкового реверса строки напрочь убило всю идею  :(*

***зы:*** ответ шутка, если вдруг кто не поймет

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не назначить стили в *CSS* и потом через *Jquery* менять класс?

```js
$("#main").on('click', '#icon' ,function(){ 
    $(this).toggleClass('minus');
});
```

```css
#icon {
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTWRf.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 20px;    
}

/* не обязательное указание*/
#icon.plus {
  background-position: 0px 0; 
}

#icon.plus.minus {
  background-position: -10px 0;
}




li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <li>
      <span id="icon" class="plus"></span>
      <!--
    <img id="icon" src="img/plus.gif" onclick="imgsrc(this)" >
    -->
    Россия
        <ul>
            <div id="RusOne"><li>Пейзажи</li></div>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) - Добавляет или удаляет заданный класс(ы) по принципу переключателя (добавляет, если элемент не содержит класса, и удаляет, если класс есть)

Comment: или  `.minus{background-image:url('minus.gif') !important;}`

Comment: @user202854 `!important` - это говнокод